# Proxying react app using nginx on docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use docker-compose to run 2 containers - a sample react app and an nginx to behave as reverse-proxy.
I've ran `npx create-react-app react-app` to create the first container, and added the following Dockerfile to the folder -

```
FROM node
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build
CMD serve -s build
```

I've then proceeded to create the following nginx configuration file under `./nginx` -

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /react {
        proxy_pass http://react:5000;
    }
}
```

Finally, I've created this `docker-compose.yaml` file in the root of the project -

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  react:
    build: ./react-app
    container_name: react-app
    expose:
      - "5000"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

I then use `docker-compose up --build` to launch my stack, but when I use the `http://localhost/react` path I get the following errors in my nginx access logs -

```
eact-app | INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:5000
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:29 +0000] "GET /react HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 2020/01/29 18:24:29 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/main.d1b05096.chunk.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/css/main.d1b05096.chunk.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/react"
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:29 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.d1b05096.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/react" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:29 +0000] "GET /static/js/2.250dc4af.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/react" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:29 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.de4c6317.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/react" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 2020/01/29 18:24:29 [error] 7#7: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/2.250dc4af.chunk.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/js/2.250dc4af.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/react"
production_nginx | 2020/01/29 18:24:29 [error] 7#7: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/main.de4c6317.chunk.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/js/main.de4c6317.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/react"
production_nginx | 2020/01/29 18:24:29 [error] 7#7: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/manifest.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/react"
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:29 +0000] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/react" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 2020/01/29 18:24:34 [error] 7#7: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/2.250dc4af.chunk.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/js/2.250dc4af.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/react"
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:34 +0000] "GET /static/js/2.250dc4af.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/react" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:18:24:34 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.de4c6317.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/react" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
production_nginx | 2020/01/29 18:24:34 [error] 7#7: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/main.de4c6317.chunk.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/js/main.de4c6317.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/react"
```

It seems to me like nginx is looking for Reacts static assets in the nginx container, but I'm not sure why doesn't it proxy these requests over to the react container. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finding [this great blogpost](https://geekflare.com/nginx-static-files-node-js/) I managed to solve the issue by changing the nginx configuration to this -

```
upstream backend {
    server react:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/src/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # Following is necessary for Websocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the symbol after the `server_name localhost§` line and how does nginx interpret it? i couldn't find an example of that in the nginx docs - `§`

Comment: It's a typo, thanks for spotting it. Should've been a `;`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used nginx to reverse proxy to my front end. Only to connect requests from my front end to my server. Instead, you might try hosting your `react-app` directly through nginx. Here is one way that I have done this.

Instead of running two containers, I set up a `Dockerfile` in the root of my `react-app`. The `Dockerfile` does a production build of the react app and then copies it into nginx to be hosted at the `/` route in your nginx configuration. This is what that file looks like.

```
# Frontend build based on Node.js
FROM node:11.12.0-alpine as build-stage
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@latest -g
COPY . /usr/src/app
#RUN CI=true npm test
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1
# Production build based on Nginx with artifacts from Stage 0
FROM nginx:1.15.9-alpine
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

In the root of the `react-app` I also have a `config` directory. Inside that directory I have `nginx.conf` file which looks like this.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }

    # redirect server error pages

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Since the frontend build is copied into nginx in the first step, it can now find the build directory inside it's own file system. After that, you can build and run the image in a container and everything should build properly. I think all you would have to do at that point is move your `docker-compose.yml` file into the `react-app` root, get rid of the `react` service, change `image: nginx:latest` to `build: .` and run `docker-compose up -d`. You could also forgo `compose` and just use docker by running `docker build -t react-app` and after that builds, run `docker run -d -p 80:80 react-app` in the root of the `react-app` directory.  This is a very simple way to get started and perhaps not quite what you were looking for. Hope it helps though.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. The trouble is that this is a local effort to try and replicate a production example in which nginx will have to serve assets and apps from remote locations. I actually pulled it off while I was waiting for the answer, I'll publish the solution now.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'd love to see how you figured that out.